Is it possible for an element to ignore the mix-blend-mode that is applied on the parent div?
so I have this code, and I'm wondering if it can show the original color by setting  mix-blend-mode: normal or isolation: isolate to the .element-to-ignore-blend-mode


body {
  height: 200vh;
  /* For scrolling */
  background: white;
}

.sticky-parent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: transparent;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  padding: 20px;
}

.element-to-ignore-blend-mode {
  isolation: isolate;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.normal-element {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
}
<div class="sticky-parent">
  <div class="element-to-ignore-blend-mode">
    This element ignores mix-blend-mode: difference.
  </div>
  <div class="normal-element">
    This element follows the mix-blend-mode: difference.
  </div>
</div>



Both elements have the same background and font color, and I expect .element-to-ignore-blend-mode to show its original color if I use either mix-blend-mode: normal or isolation: isolate (red and black).  Does anyone know how to solve this? Or maybe an alternative way to achieve the same result?
Thank you in advance
